# Error when trying to use powershell object

Tags: object, powershell

I'm trying to do something very simple, but with being new to powershell I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $directoryMaker = New-Object [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("C:\test")
New-Object : Cannot find type [[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:19
+ $directoryMaker = New-Object [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("C:\test")
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just:

```
$directoryMaker = [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("C:\test")
```

In this case you are using a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4124118/520612) ( `CreateDirectory(string s)` ) of the `[System.IO.Directory]` then you don't need to instantiate a `[System.IO.Directory]` object to reference the new folder created by this method itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I still haven't learned my way around powershell.

Comment: @inquisitor This is more c# then Powershell, the powershell way is: `$directoryMaker = new-item -Path c:\test -type directory`

Comment: Yeah I was experimenting with C# because I have to do some custom things with streams and wanted to make sure I understood how to do something more simple.  Thanks so much!