# Call to void method from static method in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, code-behind, webmethod

I have following  folder structure in my asp.net mvc 5  project. I able to call and pass parameters **OnSubmit()** webmethod using jquery script in my cshtml view-page.

[image]

now I want to call **ShowReport()** void method from **OnSubmit()** webmethod
.this **ShowReport()** method I'm using to show RDLC report wizard

How can I do this

This is summary of my web-form code-behind file **Incomplete_Prodcut.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Incomplete_Prodcut : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }       

        /// Method to show RDLC report 
        public void ShowReport()
        {
            //Reset
            ReportViewer1.Reset();

            //DataSource
            DataTable dt = GetData(type.Text, category.Text, subsidary.Text, country.Text, dateHERE.Text);

            .............

        }


        public DataTable GetData(string type, string category, string country, string subsidary, string dateHERE)
        {
            ...............

            return dt;
        }

        [WebMethod]    
        public static string OnSubmit(string type, string category, string country, string subsidary, string dateHERE)
        {

            return "";
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling non-static method from static method. This can only be achieved with initializing the class and call its non-static method.

If you have a problem understanding difference between static and non-static methods here is a short explanation.

[What's a “static method” in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4124118/716063)