# Needing an object reference for my Method?

Tags: c#

I have to make a program which generates lotto ticket then checks to see if there is a winner. I am having problems even calling my method which is only a simple menu function.

This is the error:

> Error    1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property

I am not sure where i have went wrong but i think its to do with visibility.

I have tried changing some functions to public static but that has not worked.

```
class Program
{

    bool quitFlag = false;
    SortedSet<int> winningNumbers = new SortedSet<int>();
    List<CTicket> ticketList = new List<CTicket>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DoMenu();   
    }

    public static void GenerateTickets(List<CTicket> l)
    {

        Random Rand = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i <1000; i++)
        {
            SortedSet<int> num = new SortedSet<int>();

            do
            {

                num.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Rand.Next(1,42)));
            }
            while(num.Count <=6);

            CTicket ticket = new CTicket(i,num);
            l.Add(ticket);
            ticket.printTicket();
        }
    }

    public static void DrawWinningNumbers(SortedSet<int> winningNumbers)
    {

        for(int i=1; i <6; i++)
        {

            Random Rand = new Random();
            winningNumbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Rand.Next(1,42)));

            while(winningNumbers.Count <=6);
            Console.Write("The winning numbers are: {");

            foreach (int x in winningNumbers)
            {
                Console.Write(x + ", ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    void DoQuit()
    {

        quitFlag = true;
    }

    int ShowMenu()
    {

        int option;

        Console.WriteLine("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
        Console.WriteLine( "\t\t\t Queue Application\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t1. \tGenerate tickets\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t2. \tDisplay all tickets\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t3. \tGenerate Winning Numbers\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t4. \tPrint queue\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t5. \tReverse queue\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t6. \tExit\n");

        option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        return option;
    }

    public static void DoMenu()
    {

        do
        {
            int option;

            option = ShowMenu();

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    GenerateTickets(ticketList);
                    //system("cls");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //system("cls");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    DrawWinningNumbers(winningNumbers);
                    //system("cls");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    //system("cls");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    DoQuit();
                    break;
                default:
                    //system("cls");
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid option!\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while (quitFlag != true);
    }
}
```

Comment: ive uploaded the code there. Ive tried making the DoMenu function public static void but it didnt help

Comment: Please don't link to an image of your code. Insert the code into your question and use the formatting buttons `{}` to format it as code.

Comment: Please put your code in the question.

Comment: Also please do search for the error, you will get tons of forum which explains the issue.

Comment: A quick review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c

Comment: Im sorry i wasnt aware of how to do that. And i have searched everywhere i just cant spot it in my program

Comment: If you don't know the difference between static and instance properties/methods, you're getting ahead of yourself.  Stop.  Go buy a copy of CLR Via C#.  Read it.  It shouldn't take you more than a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be clear - you are accessing non-static items (`quitFlag`, `winningNumbers`, `ticketList`) from a static method.

Either change the items above to `static` (if they should be shared by ALL instances of the `Program` class), or make the methos non-static and call it on an *instance* of `Program`.

Comment: thanks for your response. I changed all the items to static and i still have an error saying "an object reference is required for the non-static field,method or property of DoMenu. I also tried to call the function by Program.DoMenu() if that what you mean by calling as an instance

Comment: Do you know how to put in breakpoints?  My guess at this point is because ShowMenu() isn't static, it's still freaking out.  You can try setting ShowMenu to static, or you can put a breakpoint in at the beginning of "DoMenu" then step through until you find the line that breaks, and address it.

Comment: If `DoMenu` is not static then you'd need an instance of `Program` to call it - `Program.DoMenu()` would not work.