# ASP.NET & C# abs and min function

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with ASP.NET & C#.  I have this calculation I am trying to implement into C# coding, but it says abs and min math functions are not there.

This is the code:

```
private double angle(int h, int m)
{
    h = Convert.ToInt32(ddlHours.SelectedItem.Value);
    m = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMinutes.SelectedItem.Value);

    double hAngle = 0.5D * (h * 60 + m);
    double mAngle = 6 * m;
    double angle = Math.abs(hAngle - mAngle);
    angle = Math.min(angle, 360 - angle);
    return angle;
}
```

Ultimately, I want the answer to go to my label.

How do I get the abs and min function, or is there another way that still provides the accuracy of this calculation?

Comment: write Math.Abs and Math.Min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a few things;

- C# is a [case sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity) language. The right syntax of those methods are [`Math.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs) and [`Math.Min`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min)
- Depending on your structure of course but this method would be better as a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4124102/447156) since *probably* it will not need an instance to calculate this angel value.
- You don't assign your `ddlHours.SelectedItem.Value` and `ddlMinutes.SelectedItem.Value` to your parameters inside of your method. In such a case, there will be difference between `angle(5, 30)` and `angle(6, 40)` method calls since both do the calculation based on those dropdownlist values.
- Parse your dropdownlist values to integer and call your `angel` method with those parameters.

  ```
  static double angle(int h, int m)
  {
      double hAngle = 0.5D * (h * 60 + m);
      double mAngle = 6 * m;
      double angle = Math.Abs(hAngle - mAngle);
      return Math.Min(angle, 360 - angle);
  }
  ```

and call this method as;

```
int h = Convert.ToInt32(ddlHours.SelectedItem.Value);
int m = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMinutes.SelectedItem.Value);

double angel = YourType.angel(h, m);
```

Answer (score 2):

c# is case sensitive

```
double angle = Math.Abs(hAngle - mAngle);
angle = Math.Min(angle, 360 - angle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Intellisense. Its a capital A on Abs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73(v=vs.110).aspx

MSDN is your friend if Intellisense isn't working for you. Put your cursor on the words abs and press CTRL+SPACE and it will correct it for you