# C# creating extension method

Tags: c#, char

Hallo I would like to create an extension method for `Char` class that works as `Char.IsDigit()` method (but that will of course recognize a differnt type of characters).
I wrote this:

```
namespace CharExtensions
{
    public static class CompilerCharExtension
    {
        public static Boolean IsAddOp(this Char c)
        {
            return c.Equals('+') || c.Equals('-');
        }
    }
}
```

that works fine but that it's not exactly what I meant.
This extension should be used this way:

```
using CharExtensions;
char x:
...
if(x.IsAddOp())
    Console.WriteLine("Add op found");
```

While I would something like this:

```
using CharExtensions;
char x;
...
if(Char.IsAddOp(x))
    Console.WriteLine("Add op found");
```

Thanks to everyone who could help me.

Comment: You can't do that and if you could it would be pretty bad practice. Why would you want to do that? Just make a normal method and call it like this: `IsAddOp(x)`.

Comment: @DavidG _Just make a normal method_ is good but if could define Extension method its better to use that for developer

Comment: @combo_ci In what way would an extension to `char` be better?

Comment: @DavidG no i say its better to use Extension method rather than normal method, but the question mention to add a function to .Net base class that i think its not possible

Comment: @combo_ci Actually adding an extension to base framework types is also considered very bad form.

Comment: @DavidG just to have a sort o  'uniformity' of calls. Is just an aesthetic matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that, as extension methods will always require an instance of the object.
See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by using instance method syntax.

Comment: Technically they don't require an instance. They only need a variable of the correct type; whether that one is `null` or not is irrelevant for being able to call the method (although most extensions methods will require it).

Comment: @Joey Technically you do not need a variable either. You just need an expression with the correct compile-time type. For example `((IEnumerable<int>)null).First();`

Answer (score 0):

Your question mention to fire a static method of a class. You actually want to define a static method for `Char` class, not add a extension to `char` instance.  to define a static method you must access the original class  something [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)

```
class SomeClass {
    public int InstanceMethod() { return 1; }
    public static int StaticMethod() { return 42; }
}
```

Now you can use `StaticMethod` as:

```
SomeClass.StaticMethod();
```

Then you must access to Microsoft .net framework code to add `IsAddOp(x)` method to `Char` class. Actually your way to define a extension with that one you say in question is wrong.. you dont try to define `Extension` method..you try to define `Static` method.

Comment: this's NOT what I meant.