# Need to instantiate class from dll to use in other project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've created a `dll`, lets call it `ExampleHelper.dll`.

The structure of the Visual Studio Class Library which I've compiled to `dll` is the following:

```
namespace ExampleHelper
{
    public class Example
    {
        public string GetExamples(string input)
        {
            // stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So, I reference it in my other project in which I want to use these `ExampleHelper` classes, by adding a `using` line at the top of the file in question:

`using ExampleHelper;`

Now, I can see that I can access the class from `ExampleHelper`, which is called  `Example`. But, I can't access the methods in that class, which means I can't write `Example.GetExamples("hello")`, as it says `GetExamples` doesn't exist.

I noticed that I can do this:

```
Example e = new Example();
e.GetExamples("hello");
```

which I of course can use, but it doesn't feel quite right to instantiate a new object each time I want to use a helper method.

Have I done something completely wrong? My guess is yes, but I can't find where I'm going wrong. Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want to create an instance, make the method (and perhaps the class) static...

Comment: also see [What's a “static method” in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an instance of Example object to call this method.
To call a method without an instace of a object, method must be static.

```
public static string GetExamples(string input)
```

should be the method's declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Make `GetExamples(string input)` a `static` method

```
public static string GetExamples(string input)
```

Static methods do not require an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your class and methods as STATIC, you'll be able to use it everywhere.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static