# Return List<ContentInfo> - Issues problems in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#

It's like I'm just trying to get some content on my layout page for which will appear in the menu.

Right now, it only presents problems as it does not show it.

It looks like this in my "Helper" class that displays menu content.

```
public readonly DBContext _dbContext;

    public HelperViewClass(DBContext context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    public static List<ContentInfo> ListMenu()
    {
        return _dbContext.ContentInfo.Where(i => i.ShowMenu == true).OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
    }
```

Error:
**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HelperViewClass._dbContext'**

**How should it be?**

What I want this piece to do is send the content back with `showmenu == true`. That's just what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from the method.

Comment: @David Okay i remove the. But how i call the method in the view on my Layout?

Comment: Well, for one thing, calling a method *from a view* is almost always the wrong approach.  The view should just be binding to the model.  You should be calling this object from either the model or the controller to build up the data being sent to the view.  As for how you'd call this method, it's not different from calling any other method on any other object.  `someInstanceOfYourClass.ListMenu()`

Comment: i try `@foreach (var item in HelperViewClass.ListMenu())` @david

Comment: You're trying to invoke the method *statically*.  Did you *want* the method to be `static`?  If so then you can't use non-`static` class members in it.  This would be a good time for you to look up the word "static" in the C# language and learn what it means.  If you want the method to be static then it needs to create its own `_dbContext` or you need to pass one to the method.  If you want the method to use the `_dbContext` that you passed to the instance of the class then it needs to be an instance method.  Where do you create an instance of the class and pass it a value for `_dbContext`?

Comment: Okay what you say? That is, I may need to consider making a "between road from _dbContext to a new name? @David

Comment: Sorry, but I have *no* idea what you meant to say in that comment.

Comment: I cant not what u mean on what you just wrote. do you have the opportunity to come with eg?

Comment: You need to learn what `static` means and what "objects" are.  A quick Google search found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c  Just randomly adding and removing the `static` keyword until the code compiles is not how you go about solving this problem.  That keyword has a *specific* meaning in object-oriented programming.  You have to understand that meaning before you can effectively use (or not use) `static` members.