# How to understand "!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)" syntax?

Tags: c#, string, removing-whitespace, isnull, writer

Well, I know in fact that "!" means NOT, and I quite understand the "IsNullOrWhiteSpace" function destination. But once upon, when I surfed through the Internet in terms of finding how to delete whitespaces, I've faced that kind of syntax:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
{
    writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

How should I understand such a syntax? Exclamation mark before the DATATYPE(!!!), then the datatype calls the function with the parameter of my string, later being written to some file.
And, by the way, is there a better approach to delete empty lines if my file from where I read text has several (maybe, more or less) whitespaces between the actual strings?

Comment: Static method invocation?

Comment: "Exclamation mark before the DATATYPE"? Did you mean before the class' name?

Comment: ProTip: The `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns a boolean

Comment: I think you should reconsider your certainty that you understand what `!` means.

Comment: "string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)" returns a boolean. ! inverts it. Then the boolean is used in the if. It is identical to writing something like `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) != true)` or `if(!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) == true))`. You can read it as "if s is not null or a whitespace, send it to the writer". I would guess that s might be a character. If so, there is a implicitly conversion between char and string.

Comment: if might be slightly easier to read if it was written like this: `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) == false)` However I try to avoid flipping Logical operations. It is too easy to get it wrong. Personally I would propably have written a extension method "string.IsNotNullOrWhitespace()". The JiT's inlining will take care of any performance impact that might have and it reads without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you posted doesn't delete empty lines, it just skips them from writing. It means that `writer.WriteLine(s);` part not called for empty lines.

> Exclamation mark before the DATATYPE(!!!)

It's not before the datatype, it's before the call for a static method `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` of the `System.String` type. You could research [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) about it. The result of this method is boolean. So you're applying a negation operator (`!`) to the boolean result. When the result equals `true` i.e. the string passed to the IsNullOrWhiteSpace method in the `s` parameter is null or white space the negation operator is making it `false` and vice versa. After that the `if` statement takes the result of `!` operator work (`true` or `false`) and decides what to do next.

> And, by the way, is there a better approach to delete empty lines if
>   my file from where I read text has several (maybe, more or less)
>   whitespaces between the actual strings?

So you're reading from the file and writing to another or the same file. Your approach will work, but keep in mind, that `s` must be a single line from your initial file, not a word or a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

[`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_IsNullOrWhiteSpace_System_String_) is a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c) defined on the type `System.String` (which can be abbreviated as just `string`).