# C# Application - Need help implementing a loop

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to programming, I have created a simple "Guess the number" game, it functions correctly. I would like to implement a loop so the user does not need to compile the program again but rather run it through a console again.

Can you leave me an example using my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numberToGuess = 54;
    int userGuess = 0;

    while (userGuess != numberToGuess)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userGuess);

        if (userGuess > numberToGuess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is too high!", userGuess);
        }
        else if (userGuess < numberToGuess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is too low!", userGuess);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is right! Congratulations.", userGuess);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797977/c-sharp-trouble-with-integrating-loop-within-my-program ... I don't know why but that question look very similar...

Comment: How many accounts do y'all need and how many times must we be spammed by the same post?

Comment: You should consider using better variable types. A yes/no variable should use a boolean type. Booleans can have true/false values

Answer (score 2):

you can write this in main method.

```
do{
   while (EndProg == "No") {
        askData();
      }
   Console.WriteLine("Play again Y/N")
}
while("Y".Equals(Console.ReadLine()))
```