# How can be call the method from another class inherited

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

How can be call the method from another class inherited

let's see my code please:

```
class Program : classA
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // how i can call method ToDo without create an instance like below
        //classA c = new classA();
        //c.ToDo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Program2 : classB
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // how i can call method ToDo
        //ToDo()
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public abstract class classB
{
    public void ToDo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("classB");
    }
}
public class classA
{
    public void ToDo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("classA");
    }
}
```

how i can call the method in Either way, please help me.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to call `instance` method from the `static` one. That is not possible.

Comment: @Johnny Can you explain me more? not have any static keyword in my answer

Comment: Elaborating on @Johnny's answer.  A class can have two categories of members, `static` and _instance_ (those not marked `static`).  In order to access an instance member, you need an instance of the class.  Within an instance method, the instance that is used to call the method is available as `this` (which can usually be omitted).  A `static` member can be thought of as a member associated with the class (rather than with an instance).  You call it using the class name: `ClassName.MethodName();`  It can't call other instance members (since it has no `this` reference).

Comment: @Flydog57 Can you show me on  the example as answer please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a "static method" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do what you want to do (they're kind of similar or even the same).
One way is to create a class with a static method:

```
public class classA
{
    public static void ToDo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("classA");
    }
}
```

then call it like:

```
classA.ToDo();
```

Another way is to add another static method to the class that contains Main:

```
class Program2 : classB
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ToDo()
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Todo()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would really help

Comment: it's working thanks you so much, Adding an explanation please

Answer (score 0):

If u want to call ToDo() function into [class Program : classA] and [class Program : classB]
Without creating Instance.
U have to Define ToDo() function as static, then u can call this method with class name in anywhere.
`public static void ToDo(){}`