# About Instance methods in c# and unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I code in general c# and create instance methods, to call them from the same class I have to instantiate the class first and then use the method. But when using unity, The instance methods I create can be directly accessed in the same class(without instantiating the class).

Why is that ? Please help :-)

[image]

Comment: See [Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Comment: Welcome. Could you provide more details? Maybe the methods you're calling are defined in some of the base classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a "static method" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)

Comment: Please add the code of what exactly you are referring to

Comment: @Filburt I don't think this is actually about `static` at all. We will need more information from OP but as I understand it the question is about something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what everyone says here about `static` members as I understand your question it **has nothing to do with `static`** but you rather wonder why you nowhere are using `new` for your own or Unity built-in components.

Whenever a component is attached to a `GameObject` => an instance already exists because Unity already created it for you. Further there are certain properties like e.g. [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) and [`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) which Unity already populates as well for you while attaching that component to a `GameObject`.

And of course an **instance** of your custom component itself can access all of its instance members.

Comment: okay, so what you are saying is that like i created a custom component and when i am working on it, at the same time i am working on the instance of that component ?

Comment: @TheNoobestGuy what I am saying is: Please add your code and what exactly you are doing/trying to do ;) By `created a custom component` do you mean the script or do you mean you added that component to a GameObject? And by `when i am working on it` again do you mean on the script of that component or what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @TheNoobestGuy I saw you edit .. please do not edit additional information into answers but rather your question. And yes, the things you are accessing there are all **instance** members and will be called/used on a certain **instance** of that component. You didn't show as what exactly `isMovementEnabled` is declared though

Comment: isMovementEnabled is responsible for just turning the compnent off and on

Comment: so its correct to say that when i am working on the script and have instance methods, i can call them directly without instantiating the class because in the script i am actually working with some instance itself ? :-)

Comment: Well not like this no .. but yes what you mean is correct: Later you definitely will work with instances of that script, namely the components attached to GameObjects in your scene or prefabs -> so yes you will have instances

Answer (score 0):

Because of static members and classes. With the `static` keyword, you need not to instantiate the class to access its members. Also, you cannot instantiate static classes.