# How to Call a non standard Constructor

Tags: c#, syntax, constructor

I'm new to C# and having problems with the usage of a non standard constructor.
This is a part of the interface of the library I'm using (QRCoder) after the latest update:

```
public class Contact
  {
    [Obsolete("This constructor is deprecated. Use WithCombinedAddress instead.")]
    public Contact(string name, string country, string addressLine1, string addressLine2);
    [Obsolete("This constructor is deprecated. Use WithStructuredAddress instead.")]
    public Contact(string name, string zipCode, string city, string country, string street = null, string houseNumber = null);

    public static Contact WithCombinedAddress(string name, string country, string addressLine1, string addressLine2);
    public static Contact WithStructuredAddress(string name, string zipCode, string city, string country, string street = null, string houseNumber = null);
    public override string ToString();
```

Before the update, this code used to work:

```
  Contact contactCreditor;
  string name, zipCode, city, country, street, housenr, strIban;
  ... 
  contactCreditor = new SwissQrCode.Contact (name, zipCode, city, country, street, housenr);
```

Now I get the error message

> This constructor is deprecated. Use WithStructuredAddress instead.

How can I modify my code to use this new constructor?

Comment: Welcome. `WithCombinedAddress` is a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c) that can be called without having an instance of your `Contact` class. Call it like `Contact.WithCombinedAddress` and you'll get your instance - just like before.

Comment: Replace `new SwissQrCode.Contact` with `SwissQrCode.Contact.WithStructuredAddress`.

Comment: `var newContact = SwissQrCode.Contact.WithStructuredAddress(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class no longer has a non deprecated constructor, instead call the static initializer.

```
Contact contactCreditor;
  string name, zipCode, city, country, street, housenr, strIban;
  ... 
  contactCreditor = SwissQrCode.Contact.WithStructuredAddress(
                        name,
                        zipCode,
                        city,
                        country,
                        street,
                        housenr);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the necessary change. Works like a charm.